# C++ Finding a line from a text file and updating/writing the line

Tags: c++, file, text, updating

I have a bank account file that the program should be able to read. This function works as of now with the use of ifstream. But I want the program to read the 6th line of the text file (which has the value 'balance') and then update it as needed (delete and replace with new value).

I used a for loop to find traverse through the lines. But how do I **update it** when needed? **(Withdrawal and deposit of money updates the balance)**

This is the code I have for now:

```
ifstream file;
string line;
file.open ("accounts.txt", ios::in); 

for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)    //6 being the 6th line
      {
         getline(file, line);
      }
```

What comes next folks? 
Thanks :)

Comment: How big is your file going to be?

Comment: It's a small text file, with about 10 lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your file is very small like you've mentioned, you may bring it into an array of strings (one element per line of text). Then make changes to the array and re-write the whole array back to the file.

For example, you can read it into an arrya like this:

```
//assuming you've defined the array A
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)    //NOTE: I've changed the loop counter i
      {
         getline(file, line);
         A[i] = line;
         cout << A[i] < "\n"; //This is the NEW LINE I wanted you to put
         //If the ABOVE line gives nothing, you ought to check your TXT file.
      }
//Change line 6
A[5] = "555.00";
//Now reopen the file to write
ofstream Account ("accounts.txt");
if (Account.is_open())
  {
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
       {//NOTE THAT I HAVE INCLUDED BRACES HERE in case you're missing something.
        Account << A[i] << "\n"; //Loop through the array and write to file
       }
    Account.close();
  }
```

I did not test this but I think it's ok.
More code: If you add the following bit of code at the end of your main code, you should see the contents from the array. And if this shows nothing that clearly means that your file is EMPTY.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
   {
    cout << A[i] < " This is a row with data\n";
   }
```

Note: While I'd like to help you out on CLARIFYING issues on this forum, I think this question is going beyond the nature of this forum. Perhaps what you need is to spend some time learning the art of loops and other structures :)

Comment: PROBLEM: It erases every value in A[1] till 6 and only writes the value of 6. Others are empty

Comment: It is a good concept, if only it keeps the existing values of A[1] and the rest as well without erasing?

Comment: @PJ_Boy Probably an error in your code. Can you show me the code in your second for loop? Just paste it in this comment space

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)    //6 being the 6th line
             {
         getline(file, line);
         A[i] = line;
              }
              A[5] = line;
          
         }
         ofstream Account ("accounts.txt");
if (Account.is_open())
  {
    for(int j=0;j<6;j++)
        Account << A[j] << "\n"; //Loop through the array and write to file

    Account.close();
  }

Comment: Crap its all scrambled in comments

Comment: ok, first step, open your text file using any editor and check if it really has data on the first 6 lines. Second step: in the FIRST loop where we store the text in the array, Soon after we assign the text into the array, output the element. This will show us if the info is in it or not. Then let me know...

Comment: One more thing: Don't use `++i` in the loop. Rather change it to `i++`

Comment: I updated your code, check it and let me know if the display code is right? Sir, it doesnt display anything