# How can I find and replace a line of data in a text file c++

Tags: c++, file, text, io

I am trying to find and replace a line of data in a text file in c++. But I honestly have no idea where to start.

I was thinking of using 
    replaceNumber.open("test.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios_base::beg | ios::app);

To open the file at the beginning and append over it but this doesn't work.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this task?

Thanks

Edit: My text file is only one line and it contains a number for example 504. The user then specifies a number to subtract then the result of that should replace the original number in the text file.

Comment: Could you please copy the code that doesn't work for you in order to help you? Thx

Comment: If the file isn't huge you can use `std::getline()` to read in lines, adding to a `vector<string>` of lines that you want to keep, skipping over the line you don't want to keep. Then write that `vector` to a file. Though typically, for this sort of task I'll use something like `sed`.

Comment: @Adam27X My text file is only one line and it contains a number for example 504. The user then specifies a number to subtract then the result of that should replace the original number in the text file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16749090. I'm confused, though. If your text file is one line that contains a single number, there's no find/replace involved here. It's a simple read/write operation. Read the value from the file, seek back to the beginning, write the new value to the file.

Comment: I'll be honest @Ken White I was looking for a was to find and replace the number.
Instead I replaced this code with a simple read/write operation and it works fine. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using std::fstream, here's an example implementation. You open the file, iterate over each line in the file, and replace any occurrences of your substring. After replacing the substring, store the line into a vector of strings, close the file, reopen it with `std::ios::trunc`, and write each line back to the empty file.

```
std::fstream file("test.txt", std::ios::in);

if(file.is_open()) {
    std::string replace = "bar";
    std::string replace_with = "foo";
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> lines;
    
    while(std::getline(file, line)) {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
        
        std::string::size_type pos = 0;
        
        while ((pos = line.find(replace, pos)) != std::string::npos){
            line.replace(pos, line.size(), replace_with);
            pos += replace_with.size();
        }
        
        lines.push_back(line);
    }

    file.close();
    file.open("test.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);
    
    for(const auto& i : lines) {
        file << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: This has really helped me understand finding and replacing in files as I had never even touched vectors before. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::stringstream` to convert the string read from the file to an integer and use `std::ofstream` with `std::ofstream::trunc` to overwrite the file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{

    std::ifstream ifs("test.txt");
    std::string line;
    int num, other_num;
    if(std::getline(ifs,line))
    {
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << line;
            ss >> num;
    }
    else
    {
            std::cerr << "Error reading line from file" << std::endl;
            return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Enter a number to subtract from " << num << std::endl;
    std::cin >> other_num;

    int diff = num-other_num;
    ifs.close();

    //std::ofstream::trunc tells the OS to overwrite the file
    std::ofstream ofs("test.txt",std::ofstream::trunc); 

    ofs << diff << std::endl;
    ofs.close();

    return 0;
}
```